# Airflow: Can operators run on an external service, and communicate with Airflow to update the progress of the DAG?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm currently experimenting with a new concept where the operator will communicate with an external service to run the operator instead of running the operator locally, and the external service can communicate with Airflow to update the progress of the DAG.

For example, let's say we have a bash operator:

```
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_task",
    bash_command="echo \"This Message Shouldn't Run Locally on Airflow\"",
)
```

That is part of a DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
with DAG() as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task1",
        bash_command="echo \"t1:This Message Shouldn't Run Locally on Airflow\""
    )
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task2",
        bash_command="echo \"t2:This Message Shouldn't Run Locally on Airflow\""
    )
    t1 >> t2
```

[image: Current vs Experimental Flow Diagram]

Is there a method in the Airflow code that will allow an external service to tell the DAG that t1 has started/completed and that t2 has started/completed, without actually running the DAG on the Airflow instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow has a concept of Executors which are responsible for scheduling tasks, occasionally via or on external services - such as Kubernetes, Dask, or a Celery cluster.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/index.html

The worker process communicates back to Airflow, often via the Metadata DB about the progress of the task.